# template function which accepts both const char* and const std::string& params

Tags: c++

I am working on project which is essentially a wrapper for multiple both c and c++ api projects which serve relatively same purpose. Project itself also have c and c++ api. So there are many places in code when I need to process both char* and std::string type strings. 
So the question is **how I can conveniently and effectively create template function which accepts both (const) char* and (const) std::string& type params?**

for example I want to check if string is empty for both types and of course I want to add const qualifier so that it would be clear that I won't change params.

Best solution I have come so far is:

```
template<typename T>
bool is_str_empty(T&);

template<>
bool is_str_empty(const char*& c)
{
  return !c || strlen(c) == 0;
}

template<>
bool is_str_empty(std::string& s)
{
  return s.empty();
}
```

but as u can I am forced to pass std::string without const qualifier for this to work. And I clearly know that for this case I just can overload function and do not use template at all. But it's kinda not nice solution especially when number of function parameters grow.

for example I also want to write template function as this:

```
template<typename T, typename K>
void assign_str(T, K)
```

where T can be both const char* and const std::string& (source) and K
char* or std::string& (dest). So if I would do this with only overload it would be four function declarations in header instead of one template function.

Comment: Why don't you use an overloaded function instead of a template?

Comment: [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)?

Comment: @VTT, I mentioned why in my post. It's not effective solution when number of params grows but more importantly - not elegant.

Comment: @WhiZTiM, it was added in c++17. Ideally I want solution which can be build by compilers with maximum c++11 support. But thanks for idea.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::string const &` as argument and be done with it? It should accept `char const *` as well.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Obviously because constructing temporary strings will lead to considerable performance overhead.

Comment: @VTT but overload is not an option

Comment: @KilzoneKid, VTT is correct.